# What Is Netty DecoderResult and How to Use It?

Tags: netty

I'm learning how to use Netty (so totally new the the tool). I studied the HTTP server example given in Netty documentation. But I don't understand what `DecoderResult` is and how it's used in the example.

What I learned so far:
1. Decoders are to convert bytes to more complex objects. In this case bytes to `HttpRequest`.
2. In the last `ChannelInboundHandler` (after all decoding is completed) I receive my object (e.g. `HttpRequest`).
3. The implementation of `channelRead0` method of [`HttpSnoopServerHandler`](https://netty.io/4.1/xref/io/netty/example/http/snoop/HttpSnoopServerHandler.html) is quite clear: get the object, down cast, extract information, build the response, and write it when it's ready.

What I don't understand is why checking for the result of decoding (i.e. `appendDecoderResult`) is done at after reading some stuff from the `HttpRequest` object? Shouldn't I check for such failure before touching `msg`. More generally what happens when the decoding fails?

For the record, here's the part of the code which I'm confused:

```
@Override
protected void channelRead0(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg) throws Exception {
    if (msg instanceof HttpRequest) {
        val request = (HttpRequest) msg;

        // read all sort of stuff from request
        // and add them to the response buffer;

        // This is the line confused me :/
        appendDecoderResult(buf, request);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's actually the HTTP decoder, meaning it reads the data and tried to decode it into an HTTP request. While doing this it may encounter some problems which may cause the decoding process to fail. Never the less the already decoded data can be used. So I guess the order does not matter.